# android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Why this error usually arise in `listview` when i run in Android 4.0 version ,could anybody help me regarding this.I searched some sites found like using `asynctask` in `url` how could i implement it.

what i have tried:
here is the async task

```
public class GetTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Integer> {
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    public GetTask(){
    }
    protected void onPreExecute() {
                   this.progressDialog=new ProgressDialog(FirstActivity.this);
        this.progressDialog.show();
    }
    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(String... userurl) {
                         page_count=0;
                         Callpagedetails();
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if (progressDialog.isShowing())
            progressDialog.dismiss();
          listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listquestion);
         listview.setAdapter(adapterf);
    }
}
```

Using the code i receive `Null pointer Exception. Here is the log when i try the above code in 4.0 version

```
04-30 07:25:04.842: E/AndroidRuntime(1654): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
04-30 07:25:04.842: E/AndroidRuntime(1654): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
04-30 07:25:04.842: E/AndroidRuntime(1654):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
04-30 07:25:04.842: E/AndroidRuntime(1654):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
04-30 07:25:04.842: E/AndroidRuntime(1654):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
04-30 07:25:04.842: E/AndroidRuntime(1654):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
04-30 07:25:04.842: E/AndroidRuntime(1654):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
04-30 07:25:04.842: E/AndroidRuntime(1654):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
04-30 07:25:04.842: E/AndroidRuntime(1654):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
04-30 07:25:04.842: E/AndroidRuntime(1654):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
04-30 07:25:04.842: E/AndroidRuntime(1654): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-30 07:25:04.842: E/AndroidRuntime(1654):     at com.example.know.FirstActivity.Callpagedetails(FirstActivity.java:227)
04-30 07:25:04.842: E/AndroidRuntime(1654):     at com.example.know.FirstActivity$GetTask.doInBackground(FirstActivity.java:125)
04-30 07:25:04.842: E/AndroidRuntime(1654):     at com.example.know.FirstActivity$GetTask.doInBackground(FirstActivity.java:1)
04-30 07:25:04.842: E/AndroidRuntime(1654):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
04-30 07:25:04.842: E/AndroidRuntime(1654):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
04-30 07:25:04.842: E/AndroidRuntime(1654):     ... 4 more

    04-30 06:49:34.781: E/WindowManager(851): Activity com.example.know.FirstActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{40cd41e8 V.E..... R.....ID 0,0-191,168} that was originally added here
    04-30 06:49:34.781: E/WindowManager(851): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.know.FirstActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{40cd41e8 V.E..... R.....ID 0,0-191,168} that was originally added here
    04-30 06:49:34.781: E/WindowManager(851):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:354)
    04-30 06:49:34.781: E/WindowManager(851):   at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:216)
    04-30 06:49:34.781: E/WindowManager(851):   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
    04-30 06:49:34.781: E/WindowManager(851):   at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:281)
    04-30 06:49:34.781: E/WindowManager(851):   at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:116)
    04-30 06:49:34.781: E/WindowManager(851):   at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:99)
    04-30 06:49:34.781: E/WindowManager(851):   at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:94)
    04-30 06:49:34.781: E/WindowManager(851):   at com.example.know.FirstActivity$GetTask.<init>(FirstActivity.java:99)
    04-30 06:49:34.781: E/WindowManager(851):   at com.example.know.FirstActivity.onCreate(FirstActivity.java:88)
    04-30 06:49:34.781: E/WindowManager(851):   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
    04-30 06:49:34.781: E/WindowManager(851):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
    04-30 06:49:34.781: E/WindowManager(851):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
    04-30 06:49:34.781: E/WindowManager(851):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
    04-30 06:49:34.781: E/WindowManager(851):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
    04-30 06:49:34.781: E/WindowManager(851):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
    04-30 06:49:34.781: E/WindowManager(851):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    04-30 06:49:34.781: E/WindowManager(851):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    04-30 06:49:34.781: E/WindowManager(851):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
    04-30 06:49:34.781: E/WindowManager(851):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    04-30 06:49:34.781: E/WindowManager(851):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    04-30 06:49:34.781: E/WindowManager(851):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
    04-30 06:49:34.781: E/WindowManager(851):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
    04-30 06:49:34.781: E/WindowManager(851):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Could anybody help me regarding this @Thanks

Comment: It means you are doing some internet process on the main thread rather than your aync class. So confirm that is there any code raquired internet in the main thread. if so then android 4.0 will give exception.

Comment: what `Callpagedetails();` does.? is it doing any network related task?

Comment: @AnujMathur_07 yes Callpagedetails(); yes here i get the listview

Comment: Don't call `Callpagedetails();` on UI thread. Do as @Dhawal Sodha's answer.

Comment: @AnujMathur_07 i am getting the above error when i try that method

Comment: Could you post your code in `AsyncTask`.

Comment: post Callpagedetails() method..

Comment: post Callpagedetails(); method..

Comment: @PankajKumar i have added the call pagedetails part too

Comment: Seems like your two dialog showing, `ProgressDialog.show()` and `this.progressDialog.show();` are creating problem, try removing any one.

Comment: If you remove it from constructor, remember to initialize `this.progressDialog` using `this.progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(FirstActivity.this)` in `onPreExecute()`

Comment: @AnujMathur_07 still i am getting the error!!

Comment: what is on `line 227` of your `FirstActivity`?

Comment: You are getting a `NullPointerException` there, resulting in `window leaking error`. Please check, have to correctly initialized the `ListView`.

Comment: @AnujMathur_07 yes you are right but how could i make it .

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29170/discussion-between-anujmathur-07-and-priya2134412)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current problem in bellow code block

```
public GetTask(){
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(FirstActivity.this, "Loading","Please Wait");
    }

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        this.progressDialog.setMessage("Progress start");
        this.progressDialog.show();
    }
```

What happening is, when GetTask() gets called a progressdialog will be shown and after constructor call onPreExecute() will get call and this method again trying to show the same dialog.

You just need to modify your method as ..

```
public GetTask(){
            //progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(FirstActivity.this, "Loading","Please Wait");
        }

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            this.progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(yourContext);
            this.progressDialog.setTitle("Loading");
            this.progressDialog.setMessage("Progress start");
            this.progressDialog.show();
        }
```

***Happy codeing :)***

Comment: What is at line number 227... check if that is null

Comment: @ Pankaj Kumar i have used loadmorelist in line 227

Comment: We are asking about the full code of callpagedetails() but you posted some parts... check loadmorelist if any susspect can be null put null check there... and one more thing if you are updating your llistview inside callpagedetails(), DONOT DO THAT... move that code inside onPostExecute of AsyncTask..

Comment: Why i am getting this statement Emulator without GPU emulation detected.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29172/discussion-between-pankaj-kumar-and-priya2134412)

Answer (score 0):

remove this method `Callpagedetails();` from below code because you are already do this in `AsyncTask`. no need to use `Thread` again in `AsyncTask`

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                 public void run() {

                             page_count=0;
                            Callpagedetails();//here i call the url

                 }
```

just use:

```
protected Integer doInBackground(String... userurl) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
                             page_count=0;
                            Callpagedetails(); //here i call the url

                 }
```

Comment: now you are getting 'Activity com.example.know.FirstActivity has leaked window' error means You're trying to change some value in activity or showing dialog before Process complate.

Comment: if you are trying to set values in layout so Please do that in onPostExecute method not in Callpagedetails();

Comment: i have used the   listview.setAdapter(adapterf); in postExecute method but still i got the error!

Comment: using the above code i am getting the above error how could i make it right

Comment: i have added the callpagedetails part too

Answer (score 0):

This exception is thrown when an application attempts to perform a networking or threading operation on its main thread i.e. in onCreate() method of Activity- there are two solutions for that -

1) Don't do network related work in Main UI Thread, Use Async Task for that.

2) Write below code into your MainActivity file after setContentView(R.layout.main);

```
 if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
}
```

Comment: i dont need such kind of suggestion that will avoid the problem

Comment: then you should go for AsyncTask